# Python, how to read bytes from file and save it?

Tags: python

I want to read bytes from a file and then write those bytes to another file, and save that file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the basic file operations in Python. This opens one file, reads the data into memory, then opens the second file and writes it out.

```python
in_file = open("in-file", "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
data = in_file.read() # if you only wanted to read 512 bytes, do .read(512)
in_file.close()

out_file = open("out-file", "wb") # open for [w]riting as [b]inary
out_file.write(data)
out_file.close()
```

We can do this more succinctly by using the `with` keyboard to handle closing the file.

```python
with open("in-file", "rb") as in_file, open("out-file", "wb") as out_file:
    out_file.write(in_file.read())
```

If you don't want to store the entire file in memory, you can transfer it in pieces.

```python
chunk_size = 4096 # 4 KiB

with open("in-file", "rb") as in_file, open("out-file", "wb") as out_file:
    while True:
        chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
            
        if chunk == b"":
            break # end of file
            
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

Comment: The problem here is that if the file is large, then you are going to use a ton of memory (e.g., copying a 2 GB file!)

Comment: Just in case anyone else has this issue, the stopping condition should be: if piece == b'' (Double single quotes for an empty byte)
This answer helped me out a lot, but it did a few infinite loops while I sorted things out.

Answer (score 19):

In my examples I use the 'b' flag ('wb', 'rb') when opening the files because you said you wanted to read bytes. The 'b' flag tells Python not to interpret end-of-line characters which can differ between operating systems.  If you are reading text, then omit the 'b' and use 'w' and 'r' respectively.

This reads the entire file in one chunk using the "simplest" Python code. The problem with this approach is that you could run out memory when reading a large file:

```
ifile = open(input_filename,'rb')
ofile = open(output_filename, 'wb')
ofile.write(ifile.read())
ofile.close()
ifile.close()
```

This example is refined to read 1MB chunks to ensure it works for files of any size without running out of memory:

```
ifile = open(input_filename,'rb')
ofile = open(output_filename, 'wb')
data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
while data:
    ofile.write(data)
    data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
ofile.close()
ifile.close()
```

This example is the same as above but leverages using with to create a context. The advantage of this approach is that the file is automatically closed when exiting the context:

```
with open(input_filename,'rb') as ifile:
    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as ofile:
        data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
        while data:
            ofile.write(data)
            data = ifile.read(1024*1024)
```

See the following:

- Python open(): http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open
- Python read(): http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read
- Python write(): http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write
- Dive into Python File Object Tutorial: http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html

Comment: @MarkTolonen Doh! And Fixed...

Answer (score 7):

```
with open("input", "rb") as input:
    with open("output", "wb") as output:
        while True:
            data = input.read(1024)
            if data == "":
                break
            output.write(data)
```

The above will read 1 kilobyte at a time, and write it. You can support incredibly large files this way, as you won't need to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I'd rater read at least 100 kilobytes and write in another thread to speed the whole thing up, using this code

Answer (score 5):

Use the [open](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) function to open the file. The open function returns a [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects), which you can use the read and write to files:

```
file_input = open('input.txt') #opens a file in reading mode
file_output = open('output.txt') #opens a file in writing mode

data = file_input.read(1024) #read 1024 bytes from the input file
file_output.write(data) #write the data to the output file
```