# How to split .hex file as 512 bytes on python

Tags: python

I am trying to do custom bootloader for the firmware update.
I am using uart-RS485 for this purpose, so I need to split my .hex file as 512bytes, how can I do that ?
I want to select `.hex` file from my computer, get first 512 bytes and add some details on data and send, and I want to continue like this until the end of the file. what topics should i look at?

Comment: Take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787259/3279716) for reading part of a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to read bytes from file and save it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787233/python-how-to-read-bytes-from-file-and-save-it)