# I want to export a document of google drive as pdf | Google Drive Api Python

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Hi Nice to meet you : ),
I'm coding an app that one part uses a method to download a document Docx from google docs to export it as pdf but I don't know where I can see the downloaded files in python.
I'm coding with the google docs API documentation example from this URL: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python

This is my code :

```
#Block 3 : Convertir el Documento en PDF
            print("Se inicia la conversion a PDF")
            time.sleep(4)
            service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
            
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=documentId,mimeType='application/pdf')
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
            
            print("Se ha completado la descarga")
```

and the terminal says the download was complete but I can't see the Files anywhere
PD: I'm a beginner with python.

This is what the terminal says :

```
Se inicia la conversion a PDF
Download 100%.
Se ha completado la descarga
```

If someone knows a better method or a guide to make it done I will be very grateful :D!
This is a project that I'm working on my internship of software Engineering

Best Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to read bytes from file and save it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787233/python-how-to-read-bytes-from-file-and-save-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution :D

Before Changes :

```
#Block 3 : Convertir el Documento en PDF
            print("Se inicia la conversion a PDF")
            time.sleep(4)
            service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
            
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=documentId,mimeType='application/pdf')
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
            
            print("Se ha completado la descarga")
```

**After Changes (Solution)** :

```
#Block 3 : Convertir el Documento en PDF
            print("Se inicia la conversion a PDF")
            time.sleep(4)
            service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
            
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=documentId,mimeType='application/pdf')
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
            

            fh.seek(0)
            with open('newpdfboleta.pdf', 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)
           
            print("Se ha completado la descarga")
            print(fh)
```

***Edit**: I forgot a very important thing , you also need to import shutil to the code.*

```
import shutil
```

Thank you very much to the people who tried to help me!
If you have questions about this, you can ask me anytime!
you're Welcome.

**Best Regards**

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(output_filename, "wb") as output:
    while True:
        data = downloader.read()
        if data == "":
            break
        output.write(data)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787266/17613030

try this way you get the data with the downloader variable

Comment: Unclear how this addresses the question to get a PDF. Also the comment is not in English as the question is.

Comment: ¿where in my code I can add that function? best regards